# c# start process arguments pass in data

Tags: c#, command-line, batch-file

trying to pass in data from a file as a cmd line argument in c# and running into issues

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo1.FileName = @"myexe.exe";
startInfo1.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\myfolder\";
startInfo1.Arguments = "-cmd1 x -cmd2 y  < c:\\yesfile.txt";
```

the issue is with the < c:\yesfile.txt  ...

when I debug and grab the .Arguments and execute from cmd line, works fine. running from code, i get

```
Invalid command line parameters: <
```

searching around, I cant find the way to do this (pass in data) from code. The exe I am calling doesn't take in the "y" as a cmd line arg so I have to pass it in from a file to run it automatically like this.

**Update**: how to get the std input and pass in a y (based on answer) - make sure you `RedirectStandardInput = true;` as well

```
       StreamWriter inputWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;
                    inputWriter.Write("y");
                    inputWriter.Flush();
                    inputWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `startInfo1.UseShellExecute = true;`? `<, >, |` are handled by the shell (cmd).

Comment: tried that - The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order
to redirect IO streams.   I also turned of redirect input/output and tried and it doesnt seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the redirections `<`, `>` etc. are handled by the shell and not by Windows - you can't use them from Process.Start.

You could instead seed your [`Process.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) with a stream containing a 'y' and flag `startInfo1.RedirectStandardInput = true;`

Comment: do you have an example of this?